# parse.com cloud code, background job call

Tags: javascript, cloud, parse-platform, background-process

How can I call a parse background job from after save ?

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("test object", function(request) {
  // I want to call a background job HERE 
});
```

It want to fire this background job

```
Parse.Cloud.job("test job", function(request, status) {
  // save all objects (huge save)
});
```

If I can't do that in the main.js cloud code, could I call a background job in the client side (JavaScript) ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there is no way to do it via a javascript API call yet. 
In order to achieve this, I am using the REST api.

To get started, in case you've never done REST, here is something that was really helpful to debug for me: 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
Later you will call the function [Parse.Cloud.httpRequest](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Cloud.HTTPOptions.html) from Cloud code.

What you need to do is set the following:

**url:** `https://api.parse.com/1/jobs/[your test job]`    (maybe you need to encode the space to a %20 but I would recommend do start without spaces

**method:** `POST`

**request header:**

```
X-Parse-Application-Id: [your app id]
X-Parse-Master-Key: [your master key] //([find this here by selecting your app in the dropdown][3])
Content-Type: application/json
```

**payload:** `{}`  //(this will be your input data if you need some

This ways You can run a background job, but I still can't find a way to schedule it.
Hope this help!

Comment: Brilliant example, thanks.  **To schedule it** .. the best bet for now seems to be, have a process (say hourlyProcess) that runs every say hour.  In YourTestJob, don't actually do the work: just set a flag, like "do this on the next hour", 6 hours, or whatever you like.  have hourlyProcess pick up those "flags" and do the work.

Comment: This look interesting http://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Cloud.JobRequest.html, but I can't figure out how to use it.

Comment: The `JobRequest` is simply the `request` portion of defining a Cloud Code Job. `Parse.Cloud.job('myJob', function (request, status) { /* job goes here */ } );`

Comment: Is this secure? What stops someone else doing this?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper I'm SuperUberDuper late, but the master key requirement is what stops other people from doing this. Master key should not appear in any client code, it's a private key with full access to your server. The master key requirement is also why this does not appear in any client SDKs.  If you *really* want to be able to trigger background jobs from your cloud code you could add a function that uses a `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest` to `[yourServerUrl]/jobs/[yourJobName]` with the headers above, and any params you need in the body.

Comment: If you do that httpRequest I mentioned, do make sure that you have some proper authentication in place, and that it couldn't be maliciously used. I.e. don't wrap it in it's own cloud code function where you say, pass params and a job name to a cloud code function which triggers a job with the passed in params, as then any client can trigger it.  Wrap it up tight. Still probably not recommended, just possible.